# Easy way to convert SASS into CSS?

Tags: css, sass

I am using a CSS framework, which has documentation for user-created extensions. But these extensions are all written in SASS files on GitHub.
Now this framework is only a single CSS file. But for the extensions they are requiring to use NPM, or clone the entire GitHub project, and start using SASS commands, which I'm unfamiliar with. 
Is it possible that I keep the current configuration: I.e. only have the main framework CSS file, and somehow convert each extension SASS file to CSS file and add that to my `/css` folder? Or that's not possible?

**Edit: It's the Bulma CSS framework, and this is the link to the Extensions repository: [Wikiki](https://wikiki.github.io/)

Comment: You can take a look at this https://sass2css.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 3):

If the number of files are not too much, you could convert them manually using an online sass compiler

[SassMeiser](https://www.sassmeister.com) is my goto choice for online Sass compilers.

Maybe if you could provide a link to the repo, we'll have more clarity on how we could deal with it.

**Edit:** I just went through the repo. They already have the `.min.css` file for each extension in `dist` dir. You're better off just downloading the `.min.css` file rather than converting it yourself. Remember, you need the `.min.js` files also for the extension to work.

Comment: was about to write the same link

Comment: Thank you guys, I added the link to the repo

Comment: @TTnote I just went through the repo. They already have the `.min.css` file for each extension in `dist` dir. You're better off just downloading the .css file rather than converting it yourself. Remember, you need the `.min.js` files also for the extension to work.

Comment: Thanks, I saw that too, but I think it's not updated for bugs, because the comment at GitHub says that it's only the `First dist compilation`, so I guess it's never updated after that

Comment: Then it'd be best if you setup a node-sass compiler in your local and compile the files yourself.

Comment: But each extension has variables that are defined on the main SASS file. So it can't compile Is there a way to compile it anyway even without defined variables? If not I will just leave that

Comment: If you're going to compile using sass, then you'd have to compile the whole of bulma using sass. You can't compile the extensions alone and have the main bulma as css.